# drawcontours on different position

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I would like to draw contours in the middle of a blank image. I don't know how to set the contour location to be drawn. this is the line I use.

```
cv2.drawContours(bimg, c, -1, 255, 1)
```

bimg is the blank image, c is the contour I've extracted from an image. I believe I can move the contour by manipulating c, but I don't understand how c is written actually

Comment: Well, if you look at the [opencv documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a), you will see that c is a list of 2D points so you can use these points to draw the contour at the centre of the image

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the official documentation of opencv for [contours](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html). This code can be used to find contours of an image threshold and draw them on a white background with red color.

```
img = cv2.imread('image_name.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
_, cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(mask,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
bgr = np.ones((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]), dtype= 'uint8')*255 #this creates a white background of the same size of input shape
cv2.drawContours(bgr, cnts, -1, (0,0,255), 1)
```